# VB.net - How to send multiple senders to event handler

Tags: vb.net

I have MonthlyCalendar created and shown once a text box is clicked "e.g. Date of Birth". I do have multiple dates text boxes in my Form and I would like to send the actual text box as Object "clicked" along with the MonthlyCalendar as Sender as well , 3 arguments.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtDOB.Click
        Dim mc = New MonthCalendar()
        AddHandler mc.DateSelected, AddressOf DateSelected
        Me.Controls.Add(mc)
        mc.BringToFront()
        mc.Show()
End Sub

 Private Sub DateSelected(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles MonthCalendar1.DateSelected
        txtDOB.Text = DirectCast(sender, MonthCalendar).SelectionRange.Start.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    End Sub
```

I would like the handler to be like this:

1st argument the actual textbox clicked  2nd argument the Monthly Calendar 3rd argument the DateRangeEventArgs

```
AddHandler mc.DateSelected, AddressOf DateSelected(sender 'Textbox as Object, sender 'MontlyCalendar As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs)
```

Appreciate guidance and a better way of doing this

Comment: It's unclear what you mean about about the `MonthlyCalendar` that you want sent when you click the `TextBox`. You can only click one thing at once. How are they related?

Comment: @Enigmativity already answered below. Thanks

Comment: It's an answer, but I don't find it a great answer. Using `Tag` is always a kludge. I would like to suggest something that doesn't require casting from an `Object`.

Comment: @Enigmativity, well when I click the text box, I show the MontlyCalender component and then register an event once the Date is selected. Then set the textbox text the date selected. Therefore the idea here is to send the textbox as well to the event.

Comment: I've put in an answer that I feel is more scalable for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the way I'd do this. I'd avoid all of that casting you're doing.

```
Private Sub AnyTextBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtDOB.Click, txt2.Click, txt3.Click
    Dim tb = CType(sender, TextBox)
    Dim mc = New MonthCalendar()
    AddHandler mc.DateSelected, Sub (s2, e2) mc.SelectionRange.Start.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    Me.Controls.Add(mc)
    mc.BringToFront()
    mc.Show()
End Sub
```

This also avoids the separate `DateSelected` handler. Much cleaner and even more strongly typed.

The next step in making the code cleaner is to handle the closing down of your `MonthCalendar` control. Your current code and my code above doesn't do it.

Here's how:

```
Private Sub AnyTextBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtDOB.Click, txt2.Click, txt3.Click
    Dim tb = CType(sender, TextBox)
    Dim mc = New MonthCalendar()
    Dim handler As EventHandler(Of DateRangeEventArgs) = _
        Sub(s2, e2)
            mc.SelectionRange.Start.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
            Me.Controls.Remove(mc)
            RemoveHandler mc.DateSelected, handler
        End Sub
    AddHandler mc.DateSelected, handler
    Me.Controls.Add(mc)
    mc.BringToFront()
    mc.Show()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't send anything to an event handler. The object itself raises the event in response to something done to it and it sends the arguments to the event handler. You can't change the signature and you can't choose what arguments it receives.

Probably your best bet would be to, when you create the `MonthCalendar`, assign the corresponding `TextBox` to its `Tag` property.

```vb
Dim mc = New MonthCalendar With {.Tag = sender}
```

`Tag` is a general-purpose data property of type `Object`, so there's no need to cast `sender` at this point. You know that the actual object is a `TextBox`, because that's all that will raise that event.

In the event handler, you can then get the `MonthCalendar` from the `sender` and the `TextBox` from its `Tag`.

```vb
Dim mc = DirectCast(sender, MonthCalendar)
Dim tb = DirectCast(mc.Tag, TextBox)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. It worked perfectly.  As of curiosity for future reference, can we assign multiple Objects for Tag.

Comment: @Unis, you can never assign more than one thing anywhere, so no. That said, `Tag` is type `Object` so you can assign any one thing you want to it. The one object you assign can be as complex as you like.

Comment: @Unis You could get multiple objects on the `Tag` by setting it to an array or `List`.